# spartan 6 - usb keyboard

Tags: usb, fpga, xilinx, spartan

I'm attempting to use a usb keyboard to control a game I built on a spartan 6 board.  I'm struggling to understand the process to get this to work though.

I see the physical usb port on the board (I'm using a xilinx university board on campus).  I understand there are AXI IP's for usb2, but they all require a license (and won't let me export the project to sdk if I use them).

I came across the open usb source at http://jorisvr.nl/usb/.  I'm thinking this is exactly what I want/need, but I'm struggling to understand how to implement it.

Right now I think I should use xilinx platform studio to create a custom ip.  Within that custom ip make use of the vhdl source for open usb.  The process of hooking up all the different ports has me at a loss.  But the thing I don't understand the most is the PHY (UTMI) block that's required for the open usb to even work.  What is that?  Do I need to implement it?

I'm a bit lost.  Any guidance would be appreciated.  The manual for open usb can be found http://jorisvr.nl/files/fpga_usb_serial_manual.pdf.

Comment: USB keyboards operate as a different device class than the serial port emulators. None of the serial port documentation is relevant. If possible I'd look for a keyboard that supports PS/2 and use that. Some USB keyboards are dual protocol and will work with PS/2 using a passive adapter similar to mice or just find an older keyboard.

Comment: I've since learned the usb port that I'm going to connect my keyboard to works as a Human Interface Device (HID).  The board itself only supports ps/2 keyboards though, but that usb port is where they expect you to connect keyboards.  Will the keyboard recognize and be able to communicate using the ps/2 protocol even though it's connected through the usb-hid port?

Comment: Dual protocol keyboards and mice have modified USB controllers that detect the presence of PS/2 signaling and switch over to that internally. A standard USB-only keyboard won't do this. The usual PS/2 adapters just rewire the USB data signals to connect to the PS/2 clock and data pins. It sounds like your board "supports" PS/2 by expecting you to do the same with the USB port. Presumably there is a direct connection from the receptacle to the FPGA without a USB PHY chip in between. You will have to search for info to determine which pin between D+ and D- is clock and which is data.